# Migrating Windows phone 7 to Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, migration

So I have an app, which works on Windows Phone 7, however when I try "Upgrade to Windows Phone 8" the app doesn't work, and gives errors throughout the code (a few different ones including Nullreference exceptions etc)

However when I run the app on a windows phone 8 using the windows phone 7 code (without doing the "Upgrade to Windows Phone 8") the app works, it still gives an error, but atleast it works.

Now my question is, is it possible to publish the windows phone 7 code on the store to make it available for the windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want run app in WP 8 devices, perhaps you'll have a problem with the screen resolution on devices HTC. The best way is create new WP 8 project and share (add as link) most of the .cs and .xaml files of your WP7 project. I did it guided by the article [Maintaining a WP7 and WP8 version of a same Silverlight application](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application). About publish, you can select the platform for which the application will be available.